# Is the dimension of an abelian variety always finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is the dimension of an abelian variety always finite? If yes, why?

With "Abelian variety" I mean a integral scheme $X$, proper over an algebraically closed field (complete variety) with a group law $m: X\times X \rightarrow X$ such that $m$ and the inverse map are both morphisms of varieties.

Thank you!

Comment: Usually when people use the word "variety" they also include the condition "finite type over a field". See e.g p.89 of Mumford. So the answers to your first two questions are "yes, by definition". Of course you can think about infinite-dimensional group schemes if you like, but that is not part of the theory of abelian varieties.

Comment: In addition, "proper" implies finite type. Or at least it does in [the bible](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/feuilleter?id=PMIHES_1961__8_).

Comment: @Hoot: could you give a specific page reference? Thanks!

Comment: @PoohBear Definition 5.4.1 on pg 100. Part (a) is "$f$ est séparé et de type fini". Just an appeal to authority, nothing more.